Como pegar a variavel "dados" fora da função?
async function retornaDados() {

    let dados = await clientes.findOne({ where: { id: 2 } })
    return dados
}


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).

Há duas formas:
Síncrono:
retornaDados().then((dados) => console.log(dados));

Assíncrono:
let dados = await retornaDados();

Se quiser saber mais, recomendo ler os guias a seguir:

Promise
Using promises

